# MS Access: Multiple Subtotals Resulting in #Error

Tags: ms-access, expression

I have a continuous form in Access with a subtotal in the footer. It's a pretty standard subtotal. The expression is something like `=Sum(Nz([FieldA],0))`. Everything works fine when it's the only subtotal.

But for some reason, once I create a second subtotal (something like `=Sum(Nz([ControlB],0))`), suddenly **both** controls result in #Error.

Why would creating Subtotal B cause Subtotal A to result in an Error? It's not like Subtotal A depends on Subtotal B in any way.

Comment: Aggregate functions must reference field names, not controls.

Comment: Good point. I edited the question. That answers why Subtotal B would result in an error. But why should that have any effect on Subtotal A, which aggregates on a field?

Comment: That's just the way Access works. One failed calculation disrupts other (all?) calculations.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Still good to know. Thanks.